How Wall Light Junction Box Is Mounted
Our light fixture is off centr by  2 inches and thinking about moving it. However I cannot tell how the current box is mounted. Id like to know so I have an idea of how much I'd have to cut into the wall before moving. Any advice appreciated.


wiggle it around ... determine where it is attached

That's a plastic box, so unless you can see screws inside, and can't feel any wings through the gap between box and drywall, it's either nailed to an adjacent joist, screwed to some wood blocking above, or it's attached to a bracket that's fastened between joists.

ETA: if you're only moving it 2", you might as well determine where the nearest joist is, cut a hole along the center of the joist, and a large hole big enough to include the overage you're gonna need to relocate the hole.  Personally, I'd just cut out a square hole in the joist bay.  You're gonna need to repair drywall either way.
